# Drag image below another image using jquery draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a background image which has a hole into, so that we are able to see whats below it.
I place another image below background image, so that its visible through the hole. Now i need to drag that below image from the transparent hole.

Background image:
[image]

I am placing another image behind it using z-index and associating draggable with it. I want the below image to be draggable if i drag on the circular hole.
Currently it wont happen as i have associated draggable with another div which is behind and i am dragging on div above it. How can i make the drag event on above div get propagated to below div and it gets dragged?

I hope i am clear here.

my div's:

```
<div class="container">
 <div id="screen">
    <img src="kailash.jpg" class="drag-image" id="draggable"/>
 </div>
 <div id="bg">
    <img src="final.png"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Any other approach to achieve this can also be accepted.
Added the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kailash19/DZK4w/1/) example

EDIT: Asad has given nice solution below, but it doesn't work in IE and Opera. Though this can be achieved by using trigger.
just add this code in Asad's solution:

```
 $("#bg").mousedown(function(event){
     $("#draggable").trigger(event);
 });
```

and remove:

```
pointer-events: none
```

from CSS. you can find working example here(cross browser): [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kailash19/3CYd4/1/).

Hope this helps some else too :)

Comment: Can you please make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/kailash19/DZK4w/1/

Comment: I have updated your fiddle below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/DZK4w/5/). I have simply set `pointer-events:none;` on the bg div and contained image.

EDIT: As kailash has pointed out below, my original suggestion is more browser compatible, so I am reposting it here for posterity:

```
$('#bg').mousedown(function(ev) {
    $('#screen').trigger(ev);
});
```

Comment: its works, thanks. Can you please explain it? also drag is done from any part of image, can i somehow make it draggable only when clicked on hole?

Comment: Yes, I am working on that now. The explanation is simple; setting pointer-events to none means the element is now transparent to mouse interaction.

Comment: @kailash19 [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4h2Us/show/) is a slightly buggy implementation. The idea is to trigger a mouseup if the mouse is outside of the circle. The problem is that I have to estimate the radius of the circle and the coordinates of its center.

Comment: Thanks it works though :), but a bit buggy as repeated clicks outside can actually move image slowly :P.  I will accept your answer.

Comment: You will probably have to refine this somewhat, but it should work as a general approach.

Comment: I have one thought if i make the size of div(screen) of that a rectangle which just fits the circle in it and place image on it. I will be able to drag image almost only if i click on circle, your thoughts?

Comment: @kailash19 you could try that as well.

Comment: The pointer-events CSS property doesn't work for browsers that are not webkit/mozilla(IE and Opera). But i have am able to do it using trigger. You can check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/kailash19/3CYd4/1/ .. Its just to let you know

Answer (score 1):

There is a [drag event](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Draggable#event-drag) which is fired when moving the above div. Use that and just change the position of the below image according to the position of the div